# Perda de referência por parâmetro

Tags: c++, qt

Estou com o seguinte problema, ao executar o método `insereOP()` as instâncias `maq` e `cli` perdem seus dados.

Assim quando chamo o método `atualizarOP`, as informações do cliente e da maquina não existem, gerando erro no comando SQL.

```
    ClienteDAO cliDAO(con);
    Cliente * cli = cliDAO.getCliente(3);
    MaquinaDAO maqDAO(con);
    Maquina * maq = maqDAO.getMaquina(1);
    OrdemDeProducao tmp("op001",cli,maq,1,10000,QDate(2014,9,1));
    OrdemDeProducaoDAO dialogDAO(con);
    if (dialogDAO.insereOP(tmp)){
        std::cout << "Inserido" << std::endl;
        tmp.setQuantidadeProgramada(50000);
        if(dialogDAO.atualizaOP(tmp)) {
            std::cout << "Atualizado" << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

Métodos utilizados:

```
Maquina *MaquinaDAO::getMaquina(int codigoMaquina) {
    Maquina * retorno = NULL;
    if(db.open()) {
        query = QSqlQuery(db);
        query.prepare("SELECT CodigoMaquina, NomeMaquina, StatusMaquina FROM Maquina WHERE CodigoMaquina = ?");
        query.addBindValue(codigoMaquina);
        if(!query.exec()){
            std::cout << query.lastError().text().toStdString() << std::endl;
            db.close();
            return retorno;
        } else {
            if (query.first())
                retorno = new Maquina(query.value(0).toInt(), query.value(1).toString(), query.value(2).toInt());
        }
        db.close();
    } else {
        std::cout << db.lastError().text().toStdString() << std::endl;
    }
    return retorno;
}

Cliente *ClienteDAO::getCliente(int codigoCliente) {
    Cliente * retorno = NULL;
    if(db.open()) {
        query = QSqlQuery(db);
        query.prepare("SELECT CodigoCliente, NomeCliente FROM Clientes WHERE CodigoCliente = ?");
        query.addBindValue(codigoCliente);
        if(!query.exec()){
            std::cout << query.lastError().text().toStdString() << std::endl;
            db.close();
            return retorno;
        } else {
            if (query.first())
                retorno = new Cliente(query.value(0).toInt(), query.value(1).toString());
        }
        db.close();
    } else {
        std::cout << db.lastError().text().toStdString() << std::endl;
    }
    return retorno;
}

bool OrdemDeProducaoDAO::insereOP(OrdemDeProducao op) {
    if(db.open()) {
        query = QSqlQuery(db);
        query.prepare("INSERT INTO OrdemdeProducao (op, CodigoCliente, CodigoMaquina, ordem, QuantidadeProgramada, datadeentrega) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        query.addBindValue(op.getOP());
        query.addBindValue(op.getCliente()->getCodigoCliente());
        query.addBindValue(op.getMaquina()->getCodigoMaquina());
        query.addBindValue(op.getOrdem());
        query.addBindValue(op.getQuantidadeProgramada());
        query.addBindValue(op.getDataDeEntrega());
        if(!query.exec()){
            std::cout << query.lastError().text().toStdString() << std::endl;
            db.close();
            return false;
        }
        db.close();
        return true;
    } else {
        std::cout << db.lastError().text().toStdString() << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Todos os arquivos do projeto podem ser encontrados no repositório do GitHub:
https://github.com/LuanTavares/PointSW

O que pode estar causando esta perda de informação ?

Comment: Evil pointers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O tipo `OrdemDeProducao` é criado a partir de ponteiros dados a ele no construtor e desaloca estes ponteiros no destrutor.

O seu problema em especifico ocorre quando você copia um objeto do tipo `OrdemDeProducao` pois você não implementou um construtor de cópia nem um operador de atribuição. Quando isso ocorre o compilador gera uma versão padrão deles para você que simplesmente copiam cada campo da classe.

No seu caso o efeito dessas funções geradas será que ao final da cópia dois objetos do tipo `OrdemDeProducao` apontarão para os mesmos objetos do tipo `Cliente` e `Maquina`. Isso é um problema já que as duas cópias tentaram deletar os ponteiros que guardam ao ser destruídas fazendo com que a outra cópia perca os objetos que está apontando.

Esse problema ocorre justamente na chamada da função `OrdemDeProducaoDAO::insereOP` que recebe como parâmetro uma cópia de uma `OrdemDeProdução`. Ao final da execução desta função o parâmetro `op` será destruído, chamando seu destrutor que deletará os ponteiros internos do objeto. Ao retornar para a função `main` seu objeto `tmp` estará com seus ponteiros internos apontando para objetos já deletado gerando assim o problema ao utiliza-los na função `OrdemDeProducaoDAO::atualizaOP`.

Para solucionar este problema você tem que decidir se `OrdemDeProducao` toma o controle sobre os ponteiros passados para ele no construtor ou apenas observa seu estado.

Caso o objetivo de `OrdemDeProducao` seja apenas guardar referencias ao cliente e a maquina que são objetos sob controle de outra estrutura, você não deve deletar os ponteiros ao destruir pois não estão sob sua responsabilidade e serão deletados pela outra estrutura. Sendo assim, basta remover seu construtor que o programa funcionará.

Já caso o objetivo de `OrdemDeProducao` seja assumir o controle sob os objetos de `Cliente` e `Maquina` passados como parâmetro então você deve pensar o que acontece quando você copia um objeto deste tipo. As duas opções mais comum são:

1. Objetos do tipo `OrdemDeProducao` quando copiados devem criar cópias novas dos elementos apontados por seus ponteiros.

   ```
   OrdemDeProducao::OrdemDeProducao(const OrdemDeProducao& op)
   {
     this->cliente = new Cliente(*op.cliente);
     this->maquina = new Maquina(*op.maquina);
   }

   OrdemDeProducao& OrdemDeProducao::operator=(const OrdemDeProducao& op)
   {
     this->cliente = new Cliente(*op.cliente);
     this->maquina = new Maquina(*op.maquina);
   }
   ```
2. Objetos do tipo `OrdemDeProducao` não devem ser copiados.

   ```
   // Declare o construtor de cópia e o operador de atribuição
   // como privados para que o compilador gere uma
   // mensagem de erro quando forem utilizados. (pré C++11)
   class OrdemDeProducao
   {
     private:
     OrdemDeProducao::OrdemDeProducao(const OrdemDeProducao& op);
     OrdemDeProducao& OrdemDeProducao::operator=(const OrdemDeProducao& op);

     // Resto das definições das declarações da classe
     // ...
   };
   ```

Caso você escolha a segunda opção, terá que modificar todas as funções que recebem por valor como parâmetro objetos do tipo `OrdemDeProducao` para que recebam o mesmo como referências, constantes ou não dependendo do caso. Assim, sua função `OrdemDeProducaoDAO::insereOP` mudaria para:

```
bool OrdemDeProducaoDAO::insereOP(const OrdemDeProducao& op);
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado Tiago, Eu imaginava que era por estar passando por ponteiros mas estava perdido em como resolver. Literalmente uma aula sobre ponteiros. Novamente muito Obrigado.

Comment: De nada! Caso queira se aprofundar mais sobre quando deve ou não criar construtores de copia e operadores de atribuição faça uma busca sobre "Rule of Three" em C++. (Caso você esteja usando C++11, procure por "Rule of Five" ou "Rule of Zero")